# Accessing Django models while Testing

Tags: django, unit-testing

I would like to know whether it is possible to access the current models stored in the db while doing testing in Django.

Thanks!

Comment: You  mean values from the current models? why you want to do that?

Comment: You can get the model from apps object.

Comment: How can I do that? how can i initiate the app object? I would like to check in my test how many rows are in one of my already populated tables since I parse a csv to populate the DB. Thats why I ened the access

Answer (score 0):

You can use ipdb:

```
pip install ipdb
```

Then in the test function put a break point:

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

You'll have an interactive shell when running your test where you can access all the values the same way you do in your code `Model.object.....`

Comment: When you're testing your code using "manage.py test" Django create a testing database and destroy it at the end of your tests => you can't access it using shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you need data in your tests, you should create [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/) for it.

Fastest way to do this is to use `./manage.py dumpdata --help`.

Store the output in your project tree in order to be able to load it from a test. You can use a setting like `FIXTURES_DIR` but that is not a requirement. You could also store the fixture files near the tests they belong to.

My experience led me to create several small fixture files that only contain certain models. For example, I have a small fixture file that only contains some user that I need in the tests. This fixture is loaded everywhere that needs authentication. Of course, all other fixtures that contain data relating to User objects need to either be changed to these test users or the related users need to be added to the fixtures, as well. You will have to try around and fix your fixture data so that it is complete for your tests. You most likely don't want to have all of your production data as test fixtures.

In your tests you specify the fixtures like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class SomeTest(TestCase):
    USER_DICT = {
        'username': 'django-test',
        'password': 'XXX'
    }

    fixtures = [
        # fixture for django-test and other users
        os.path.join(settings.FIXTURE_DIR, 'auth_fixture.json'),
        # core models for some app
        os.path.join(settings.FIXTURE_DIR, 'core.json'),
    ]

def test_one(self):
    # uses clean fixtures
    # modify, delete or add data
    pass

def test_two(self):
    # uses clean fixtures
    # the changes of test_one have been reset
    pass
```

This will automatically load the fixtures for each test. You can modify, delete, add data during one test (single test method), and all of it will be reset to the original fixture data for the next test (next method).

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!

Is it a good idea?? Hopefully there are easier and safer ways to accomplish what you're intending.

By default django test runner [creates a database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) prepended with `test_`, in part to protect your databases from accidentally having destructive tests executed against them!

Because django's models are so tightly integrated with the test runner integration tests (writing tests that actually interact with the database are extremely fast).  This is mainly because each test is executed within a transaction, and during test teardown the transaction is rolled back.  Because tests are so fast the convention is to create your test data (fixtures) within each test, as needed, instead of relying on a global database state.  This also has the effect of making your tests more isolated and focused.

---

Of course there are many cases where you may want to test against production.  To do this you could use the regular test runner (`unittest.TestCase`, so no test database is brought up) and then import your models directly, and query your database.

But if your intention is to "I would like to check in my test how many rows are in one of my already populated tables since I parse a csv to populate the DB". Then why can't you create a django unit test, where you have a fake CSV, execute the code to parse/load it and then query your database, within the context of your testcase?? It provides so much protection and speed to do it within the context of django test case.

If you DO end up creating some sort of functional/automated test that queries the data base directly, it would probably be a good idea to create a READ ONLY database user.